# Poincaré map is taking lots of time

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, performance-tuning, numerics

I'm trying to build a Poincaré map of the following differential equation,

```
r'[ϕ]==(Sqrt[e (1 + ((-1 + c) M)/(2 - (3 M)/r[ϕ])) - (1 + ((-1 + c) M)/(
 2 - (3 M)/r[ϕ])) (k + l^2/r[ϕ]^2) (1 - (2 M)/
 r[ϕ])] r[ϕ]^2)/l
```

I set the Mathematica's example to my problem, and my code is the following:

```
M = 1; k = 0; l = 3*Sqrt[3]*M; e = 1; c = 2;

abc = {r'[ϕ]==(Sqrt[e (1 + ((-1 + c) M)/(2 - (3 M)/r[ϕ])) - (1 + ((-1 + c) M)/(
 2 - (3 M)/r[ϕ])) (k + l^2/r[ϕ]^2) (1 - (2 M)/
 r[ϕ])] r[ϕ]^2)/l};

pscect[{r0_}] := 
 Reap[NDSolve[{abc, r[0] == r0, WhenEvent[Mod[ϕ, 2*π] == 0, Sow[{r[ϕ]}]]},
 {}, {ϕ, 0, 20*π}, MaxSteps -> ∞]][[-1, 1]]

abcdata = Map[pscect, {{2.5}, {2.7}}];
ListPlot[abcdata, ImageSize -> Large]
```

The idea is plot the value of `r[ϕ]` each time that the angle `ϕ` is a multiple of $\pi$, but when I run my code, it takes a very long time and never ends... is there any mistake in my code? Is the differential equation too complicated?

Comment: Is `r'[ϕ]` supposed to be imaginary?

Comment: @ChrisK No, $r'(\phi)$ must be real, I fixed the parameters.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, but eventually you should either clarify your question or [accept and answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)**. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved symbolically as follows.  First, obtain `r[ϕ]`.

```
sr = DSolveValue[abc, r[ϕ], ϕ]
(* InverseFunction[-((2 (-3 + #1) Sqrt[(-1 + #1)/#1] 
   (2 EllipticPi[5/3, ArcSin[Sqrt[(6 + #1)/#1]/Sqrt[5]], 5/7] 
    Sqrt[2 - 18/#1^2 + 9/#1] + 3 EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[(6 + #1)/#1]/Sqrt[5]], 5/7] 
    Sqrt[2 - 3/#1] Sqrt[(6 + #1)/#1]))/(3 Sqrt[21] (-3 + 2 #1) 
    Sqrt[((-3 + #1)^2 (-6 + 5 #1 + #1^2))/(#1^3 (-3 + 2 #1))])) &][ϕ/3 + C[1]] *)
```

where `C[1]` is an arbitrary constant.  Because `InverseFunction` often is slow and inconvenient to use, instead determine `ϕ[r]`.

```
sϕ = 3 Head[sr][[1]][r] - 3 C[1]
(* -((2 (-3 + r) Sqrt[(-1 + r)/r] (3 Sqrt[2 - 3/r] Sqrt[(6 + r)/r]
   EllipticF[ArcSin[Sqrt[(6 + r)/r]/Sqrt[5]], 5/7] + 2 Sqrt[2 - 18/r^2 + 9/r]
   EllipticPi[5/3, ArcSin[Sqrt[(6 + r)/r]/Sqrt[5]], 5/7]))/(Sqrt[21] (-3 + 2 r) 
   Sqrt[((-3 + r)^2 (-6 + 5 r + r^2))/(r^3 (-3 + 2 r))])) *)
```

This result can be plotted, here for `C[1] = 0`, by

```
Quiet@ParametricPlot[{sϕ, r}, {r, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
    AxesLabel -> {ϕ, r}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotPoints -> 10000, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]]
```

[image]

Nonzero `C[1]` shifts the plot to the left or right.  For instance, the plot appearing in the answer by [ChrisK](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6358/chris-k) is obtained (with `C[1]` set to zero and the plot offset by `sϕ /. r -> 2.5` for convenience) by

```
sϕ /. r -> 2.5
Quiet@ParametricPlot[{sϕ - %, r}, {r, 2.5, 3}, PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {2.4, 3.2}}, 
    AxesLabel -> {ϕ, r}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotPoints -> 10000, 
    ImageSize -> Large, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Medium]]
(* 2.82612 *)
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The corresponding first six values of `r[ϕ]` for which `ϕ` is a multiple of `2 π` are

```
sϕ /. r -> 5/2;
Table[r /. FindRoot[sϕ - % == 2 n Pi, {r, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
    MaxIterations -> 1000], {n, 6}]
(* {2.99992603228136152927874105240, 2.99999998976689106071829908658, 
    2.99999999999858430887132134517, 2.99999999999999980414736314611, 
    2.99999999999999999997290492637, 2.99999999999999999999999625156} *)
```

In fact, even for the smallest allowed positive value of `r0`, namely `3/2` (see first plot in this answer), the corresponding values of `r[ϕ]` are

```
N[sϕ /. r -> 3/2 + 10^-30, 30]
Table[r /. FindRoot[sϕ - 2 == 2 n Pi, {r, 2}, WorkingPrecision -> 30, 
        MaxIterations -> 1000], {n, 6}]
(* 2.04787218611504152367838688217 *)
(* {2.99977765913514283034083671722, 2.99999996923948427891300637665, 
    2.99999999999574446147280852007, 2.99999999999999941127098637529, 
    2.99999999999999999991855276405, 2.99999999999999999999998873225} *)
```

All results are very near `3`.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but an extended comment.

Let's plot the right hand side:

```
Plot[(Sqrt[e (1 + ((-1 + c) M)/(2 - (3 M)/r)) - (1 + ((-1 + c) M)/(2 - (3 M)/r))
  (k + l^2/r^2) (1 - (2 M)/r)] r^2)/l, {r, 0, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looks like there is a semistable equilibrium at `r=3`.  Numerically solving the system now:

```
sol = NDSolve[{abc, r[0] == 2.5}, {r}, {ϕ, 0, 10 π}, MaxSteps -> ∞][[1]]
(* NDSolve::ndsz: At ϕ == 26.275649417504575`, step size is effectively zero;
  singularity or stiff system suspected. *)

Plot[r[ϕ] /. sol, {ϕ, 0, 10 π}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At some point `r` must have jumped over `r=3` due to numerical errors, which sets the run away later.

Comment: In fact, there's a semi stable equilibrium in $r = 3$, I wanna plot the poincaré maps to show that the orbits close to this point tend assymptotically to $r = 3$ by one side and diverges by the other side. This system is just valid for $r > 2$ by the way.

Comment: You can see that from `NDSolve`.  Since it's not a periodic system, I'm not sure what more you get from the Poincare map.

Comment: I can't say that $r \to 3$ as $\phi \to \infty $ using NDSolve. I hope to see this graphically through the Poincaré Map.

Comment: I don't see the difference, but anyhow it's clear that there's a singularity at ϕ~26.5, so you'll have a hard time with `NDSolve` beyond that point.

Comment: What about using runge-kutta and symplectic partitioned runge-kutta (sprk) methods? If this is a hamiltonian system, sprk would work well.